# What is throughput as far as processors are concerned?

Tags: processor, algorithm

My teacher showed some algothrims, RR, FCFS and others. In the end he exposed a table with throughput of the algorithms. He explained what thoughput is but he failed miserably. He first said that throughput is like a pipe, so all the students thought, "the higher the throughput the better" after being asked if the higher the throughput the better" he contradicted himself. In another words it was better to give up and search online. I searched online but the explanations seems too complicated for me. What is throughput in very very simple words?

Comment: sometimes a shorter pipe is better than a wider but longer pipe.

Comment: A taxi will get you to your destination faster, but a bus has higher throughput.

Answer (score 4):

Throughput is *some measure* of the capability of an algorithm to *get things done*. When you've defined what exactly is your measure, you'll have a better idea of what throughput is measuring. It might mean percentage time servicing all tasks, it might mean time servicing high priority tasks, it might mean something else.

In the case of a Round Robin versus a First Come First Served scheduler, there is obviously a significant latency difference between the two. A Round Robin scheduler is also known as an [Alice's Resturant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice%27s_Restaurant) scheduler, as you have to wait for 'the chorus to come around' before your task gets serviced. Under even light load, this can mean that a repeatedly queued task, like a keyboard handler which handles a single character at a time, can take longer than you expect, acting on a queue of key presses one - at - a - time, very tedious.

It's not obvious that either would spend longer swapping tasks so not spending time on useful work, is the task queue pre-emptive, are the tasks active-time-limited? These assumptions, plus some assumptions of the task arrival statistics, and any other relevant constraints like limited memory requiring swapping, would have to be taken account of in modelling throughput.

Comment: It's obvious that a round-robin scheduler swaps tasks more, because a FCFS scheduler only swaps once per task, and a RR scheduler can swap one or more times pre task.

Comment: @user253751 It depends what you define as a 'task swap', whether you count the scheduler as a task. RR requires tasks to be interruptible , FCFS does not, so it's an apples and oranges comparison

Answer (score 3):

Throughput is the number of instruction/bytes/etc processed per second or per cycle. It is contrasted with latency, which is how long each individual thing takes to process. Essentially, throughput is 'how much' while latency is 'how long'.

Rather than pipes, I like pregnancy as an analogy. A typical pregnancy has a throughput of one baby and a latency of 9 months. Twins have a throughput of 2 babies but latency is still 9 months since each baby always takes the same amount of time.

Comment: +1 for the twins analogy

Comment: And a breeding party of 9 cows (switch to animals for obvious reason..) still has a latency of 9 month to produce one calf. (They will of course produce 9, but that doesn't lower the 9 months). But they have a calving rate of 1 per month.

Comment: Note also that due to twins and triplets, 9 cows have a theoretical maximum output of 27 calves in 9 m with triplets.